# gem install raises segmentation fault with ruby 1.8.7, rbenv and no other local gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've got the old project to maintain on ruby 1.8.7, but I can't install bundle because there's no bundler installed for it currently and trying `gem install bundler` raises Segmentation fault. In fact it doesn't depend on gem, `gem install <any gem>` has the same result.

A few hours of googling had no effect, so here are the details:

```
$ gem install bundler
/home/marat/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
Aborted
```

Environment details:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/marat/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/marat/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/marat/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/marat/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/marat/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

No local gems currently:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using older version of gcc helped me. Here're the steps I took to resolve the issue in my case:

**Add repositories containing older versions of gcc for Ubuntu 16.04 and install it:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gcc-4.4
```

**Build project using older gcc:**

```
rbenv uninstall 1.8.7-p352
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.4 rbenv install 1.8.7-p352
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.4 rbenv local 1.8.7-p352
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an OpenSSL problem. You can run:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/opt/local" rbenv install 1.8.7
```

This will give you a clean install of Ruby 1.8.7 with the correct OpenSSL information. You may want to do `rbenv uninstall` first.

Update:

Another way to tackle this is to change `source 'https://rubygems.org'` to `source 'http://rubygems.org'` in your Gemfile.

Comment: @Marat Added another  option. Hopefully this one will work!

Comment: @Marat Drat. Well, I'll let you know if i find anything.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to install latest version of bundler that does not support ruby 1.8.7(refs [here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/bundler.gemspec#L35)). Try to install bundler version 1.7.3 or lower. Example:
`gem install bundler -v=1.17.3`

Comment: Thanks, but defining a version does not help